# All Audio Outputs Listed as "unavailable", "unplugged" in pavucontrol. Dummy Output Listed in Audio Settings

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, pavucontrol

I'm a new Linux user, Windows 10 refugee. Everything is working well except for audio in my Ubuntu installation. As the title says, in the audio settings, the only audio option is "Dummy Output". When I try pavucontrol, the audio choices are all listed as "unplugged" "unavailable". I've tried many fixes, such as restarting alsa and going into alsamixer. But nothing I try has worked.

I've got an AMD® Fx(tm)-6300 six-core processor and a Radeon RX550/550 Series graphics card. I use the headphone jack on my monitor to get audio.

here's the output of `hwinfo --sound`

```
9: PCI 100.1: 0403 Audio device                                
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: NXNs.7IS0FEaF4_0
  Parent ID: 8otl.1zYaSjlK1pF
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:01:00.1
  SysFS BusID: 0000:01:00.1
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "ATI Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X]"
  Vendor: pci 0x1002 "ATI Technologies Inc"
  Device: pci 0xaae0 "Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X]"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0xaae0 
  Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"
  Memory Range: 0xfea60000-0xfea63fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 37 (201 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00001002d0000AAE0sv00001462sd0000AAE0bc04sc03i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #13 (PCI bridge)

30: PCI 14.2: 0403 Audio device
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: 5Dex.c8pPfvNvCx4
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:14.2
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "ATI SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)"
  Vendor: pci 0x1002 "ATI Technologies Inc"
  Device: pci 0x4383 "SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1849 "ASRock Incorporation"
  SubDevice: pci 0x5892 
  Revision: 0x40
  Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"
  Memory Range: 0xfeb00000-0xfeb03fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 16 (1836 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00001002d00004383sv00001849sd00005892bc04sc03i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```

output of `cat /proc/asound/cards`

```
0 [SB             ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI SB
                      HDA ATI SB at 0xfeb00000 irq 16
 1 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
                      HDA ATI HDMI at 0xfea60000 irq 37
```

output of `lspci -v` for sound

```
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 37, NUMA node 0
    Memory at fea60000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Update: my Ubuntu version is 20.04

I hope this is enough info

thanks in advance